# Leaflet extending canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, leaflet, extend

I'm trying to extend the canvas in Leaflet 1.4 [like this](https://codepen.io/tforward/pen/ZPzeQY?editors=1010):

```
L.Canvas.FPCanvas = L.Canvas.extend({
  options: {
    width: 1,
    height: 1
  },

  initialize: function(name, options) {
    this.name = name;
    L.setOptions(this, options);
  },

  onAdd: function (map){},

  onRemove: function (map) {}
});

L.canvas.fpCanvas = function(id, options) {
  return new L.Canvas.FPCanvas(id, options)
}

console.log(L.canvas.fpCanvas("fpCanvas", {width: 10, height: 10}))

const myRenderer = L.canvas();
console.log(myRenderer)
```

When I log my extended canvas to the console everything up the prototype chain looks good. However when I log the code below:

```
const myRenderer = L.canvas();
console.log(myRenderer)

_layers: {}
_leaflet_id
```

These two additional properties appear, while I was expecting them to be the same. How do I modify my canvas extend to include these additional properties, assuming I need them to work with extended custom canvas. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the `L.Canvas.initialize()` implementation with your own - therefore, the *default initialization is not happening*.

Let me quote from the [Leaflet tutorial on class extension](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html):

> Calling a method of a parent class is achieved by reaching into the
>   prototype of the parent class and using `Function.call(…)`. This can
>   be seen, for example, in the code for `L.FeatureGroup`:
>
> ```
> L.FeatureGroup = L.LayerGroup.extend({
>
>     addLayer: function (layer) {
>         …
>         L.LayerGroup.prototype.addLayer.call(this, layer);
>     },
>
>     …
> });
> ```
>
> Calling the parent’s constructor is done in a similar way, but using
>   `ParentClass.prototype.initialize.call(this, …)` instead.